# PHP error while saving text file

Tags: php

I wanna save on my server a text file and so I'm using the `file_put_contents` with some flags. I also have to import a value from an `<input type="text" name="loaded">` field that contains some people's names.

```
<input type="text" name="loaded">
 //other html code
<form method="post" action="scriptf.php">
<input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

This script saves on foldera/file.txt only "Lucas Smith (lsmith334) +" but it is missing the `ex` (which contains the text in that input).

```
<?php
$file = 'foldera/file.txt';
$ex = $_POST['loaded'];
$person = "Lucas Smith (lsmith334) + ".$ex;
file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so do a `var_dump($_POST)` and/or `var_dump($ex)` to ensure that your extra data is actually coming through. As written, this code is fine.

Comment: though i wouldnt let a post variable dictate the path with no filtering

Comment: so if I put "var_dump($_POST)" instead of "$ex = $_POST['loaded'];" it should work?

Comment: Your `input` must reside inside your `form` element!

Answer (score 0):

your input isn't inside the form

```
<form method="post" action="scriptf.php">
<input type="text" name="loaded">
<input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

should work, all of the inputs need to be inside the form tags

Nesting forms is a bad idea, and should be completely avoided, I can't think of a good reason to nest them

its actually agaist the standard too 
[Can you nest html forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)

multiple forms is no problem, nested forms is

Comment: I have other 2 <form> in my page. Isn't this a problem? Inside the <form> you posted I'm gonna put another form

Comment: why nested forms ? the submit button which is pressed is the form which is sent. Nested forms are a bad idea

Comment: eh I have a <form> because I'm importing a Javascript function from an external file, I need that

Comment: That doesnt make sense ? you need a script to import a javascript function ?

Comment: Yes it does and yes I need.

Comment: Could you give a better example - i cant think of a single situation where nested forms would be the wanted outcome